# Cannot access implemented interface

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm writing a test and when I try to get the activity from ActivityTestRule with getActivity() there is an error that says cannot access some view listener of a 3rd party library (in my case it is com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.OnQueryTextListener). My activity implements this listener.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


@Test
public void testStuff(){

        RecyclerView recyclerView = mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(com.cobox.core.R.id.recyclerView_hp);
        int itemCount = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    }
```

The MainActivty class implements also other interfaces but they all in the inner projects or override from the android support library.

Thanks for helping me to figure this out (:

**Edit:**
This is the error from the Build output window:

> error: cannot access MaterialSearchView
>           RecyclerView recyclerView = mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(com.cobox.core.R.id.recyclerView_hp);

```
class file for com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView not found
```

Comment: Could you include the specific error? It's kind of hard to tell otherwise...

Comment: @npace I have edited my answer and added the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I figured it out, I wrote tests in a different module and as a result the dependencies in one module did not recognized in the other module. After adding the missing dependencies to where the test library was the tests compiled and could be tested.